# iDangero.us swiper fade

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I wanted to use the [iDangero.us jQuery swiper plugin](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) for a long row of tabs, in free-mode. To make it intuitive I tought I'll put two fades to the ends (to the left and respectively right) of the swiper-container. But I want to show these only when the swiper wrapper has hidden region on that end (for example, when the user swipes a bit left, so a part of a tab start's disappearing at the left side, the gradient should appear). Here's an image showing what I mean:

[image]

I almost made it, except for two issues:

1. I couldn't find any **onSwipeAnimationEnd** like event for the swiper. There is an **onTouchEnd** (I'm using currently) but there is still animation after you release the swiper, so it doesn't always works correctly.
2. When using the **initialSlide** option, the **onFirstInit** event handler has a **position.offset** parameter of 0. This event is called before the slider is moved to it's initial position. I want to use this to initialize the visibility of these gradients.

I took a look inside the plugin but I don't understand much of it. I'm hoping for a simple solution, or some guides on how to modify this plugin to satisfy my needs. I hope you guys can help. I don't want to use other swiper plugin, I'm very satisfied with this. It works very well on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question you can use additional onSlideChangeEnd and onSlideReset callbacks to cover this animation after touchEnd. For the second question you can use getWrapperTranslate method to get offset, you may not use it within onFirstInit callback, just use it after initialization code. If it will not work, just try to use it after small timeout about 50ms using setTimeout

Comment: onSlideChangeEnd and onSlideReset don't work with freeMode. But the other thing you recommanded, I might be able to use that. Not a very pretty solution, but might work. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: The setTimeout trick tpogether with the getWrapperTranslate worked well, thanks. I only need something for the animation end...

Comment: You can use mySwiper.wrapperTransitionEnd(callback function here) method for animation end

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that, thanks a lot. This also doesn't work in all cases, but works in every case where onTouchMove doesn't work. So the two together solved my problem.